# CreateRemoteThread: Returning thread exit code to caller

Tags: c#

I've injected into a remote process, using unmanaged c++ code, and calling `CreateRemoteThread()`, as well as waiting for the exit code of that thread:

```
WaitForSingleObject(hThread, (uint)ThreadWaitValue.Infinite);
```

I use [`DllExport`](https://github.com/3F/DllExport) to export the c# function to unmanaged code (Where I find the pointer, and call the specific function in my c# code.)

I'd like in certain circumstances for my c# code to return an error back to my unmanaged handler in special cases. If I throw an uncaught error, it bubbles back up into the global unhandled exception handler, and those handlers handle the error (In their own way), and thus never bubbles back to the exit code for the thread.

From the c# entrypoint, is it possible to provide an exit code back to the function calling this thread?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodethread

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, but how do I do that from c# managed code? The only way I've found to be able to do this, was to throw an exception in the thread, which does bubble back to an error to the caller, but I'm unable to do this in this instance, as there is an unhandledexception handler.